# How to solve Terrain splat null issues on unity editon?

Tags: unity-game-engine, terrain

I've an issues on my unity editor. It showed the following error. Anybody knows how to solve this?

Terrain splat 4 is null.
UnityEditor.DockArea:OnGUI()

Comment: Did you check whether Terrain splat 4 is null?

Comment: Actually i didn't understand the type of this problem. It just shows the error! BTW, how can i check that if it's really null or not!?! And what does 'splat' means please?